# Angular 4+ directive that access component NgModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to change styles due to `NgModel.control` state. Since I wanna do it DRY, I thought that a directive *reading* component `NgModel` state will do the trick.

Is that even possible? Couldn't find any hints on how to do it.

My idea would so I can write something like this:

```html
<div class="fields">
    <app-dummy-selector name="dummy" 
        [(ngModel)]="dummy" required appValidationError>
    </app-selector-moneda>
</div>
```

And then, my directive be defined with something like this

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appValidationError]'
})
export class validationError {
  // do some logic to add Styles via Renderer2 or ElementRef
  // based on NgNodel control state 
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

}
```

To clarify **UPDATE**, what I ld like to avoid is to avoid adding `#ctrl="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ error: (ctrl.invalid) && ctrl.touched }"` like this:

```html
<div class="fields">
    <app-dummy-selector name="dummy" 
        #ctrl="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ error: (ctrl.invalid) && ctrl.touched }" 
        [(ngModel)]="dummy" required appValidationError>
    </app-selector-moneda>
</div>
```

Comment: do u need to change the styles according to the ngModel value ?

Comment: I wanna change the style based on `ngModel` state not the value (I update the question providing more information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **inject [`NgControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl) on the host** to access the control.

```
constructor(@Host() private ngControl: NgControl) { }
```

---

As for **handling errors** on the view which your questions seems to be about after your update, I can suggest the following two packages. (Full disclosure, they're mine.)

- https://github.com/lazarljubenovic/ngx-common-forms
- https://github.com/lazarljubenovic/ngx-sin

It's built to handle cases such as yours to reduce boilerplate.

Comment: What about reacting to touch event? `NgControl` allow me to check for `statusChanges` but no `touchChanges`... :(

Comment: @genuinefafa There's no `statusChanges` on the control, no matter how you access the control. It simply doesn't exist yet.